# My pos_tag goes through each letter, I need it to apply to the entire word

Tags: python, xml, nltk

I am working on creating a python template for any input text that will create 
 XML entries of each word and what POS (Part of Speech) it belongs to.

I am using pos_tag from nltk, but when I take the word and try to tag it, it tags each letter instead of the entire word.

```
for word in textList:
    if word in typeList:
        tokenRest += 1
    else:

        wordXML = '<word number="' + str(corpusList) + '">'
        wordformXML = "<wordform>" + word + "</wordform>"
        posTag = "<POS>" + str(pos_tag(word)) + "</POS>"
        fullWordXML = wordXML + "\r\n" + wordformXML + "\r\n" + posTag + "\r\n"
        resultList.append(fullWordXML)
        typeList.append(word)
        corpusList += 1


print (resultList)
```

At `posTag = "<POS>" + str(pos_tag(word)) + "</POS>"` I am expecting the pos_tag with the word in it to output a dictionary with the word and its POS tag. What I get is a dictionary with each letter of the word with a POS tag for each letter. Like this:

The wordform "seeming" is out put like `<POS>[(\'s\', \'NN\'), (\'e\', \'NN\'), (\'e\', \'IN\'), (\'m\', \'NN\'), (\'i\', \'NN\'), (\'n\', \'VBP\'), (\'g\', \'NN\')]</POS>`, which should output like this:

`<POS>[(\'seeming\', \'NN\')]<POS>`

Is there a way to make sure the pos_tag works on the entire word, or should I use something else?

PS: I am working on extracting just the tag as a string from the dictionary as well, so the finished code will not look like this. Currently, I just need help with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nltk.tag.pos_tag` expects a list of tokens. If you supply it with a string, it uses that as a list instead, and interprets each character as a token, and tries to assign a POS to each. With the variable "word", you could do `pos_tag([word])` instead, to operate on a single word.

See the [NLTK documentation on pos_tag](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html?highlight=pos_tag#nltk.tag.pos_tag) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and further documentation!